# Rename categorical variable according mean of another variable in R

Tags: r, refactoring, tidyverse, rename

I would like to rename a categorical variable according to the value of an other continuous variable.

```
set.seed(123)
temp <- data.frame(label = as.factor(c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5))), 
                   number = c(runif(5, min =5, max = 12), runif(5,min = 3,max = 8)) ) %>% tibble()

>temp
  label number
   <fct>  <dbl>
 1 1       7.01
 2 1      10.5 
 3 1       7.86
 4 1      11.2 
 5 1      11.6 
 6 2       3.23
 7 2       5.64
 8 2       7.46
 9 2       5.76
10 2       5.28


temp_update <- temp %>% group_by(label) %>%
   mutate(mean_numb = mean(number)) %>% arrange(mean_numb) %>% 
                     mutate(mean_numb=as.factor(round(mean_numb,2))) 


> temp_update
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   label [2]
   label number mean_numb
   <fct>  <dbl> <fct>    
 1 2       3.23 5.47     
 2 2       5.64 5.47     
 3 2       7.46 5.47     
 4 2       5.76 5.47     
 5 2       5.28 5.47     
 6 1       7.01 9.63     
 7 1      10.5  9.63     
 8 1       7.86 9.63     
 9 1      11.2  9.63     
10 1      11.6  9.63
```

In this small example, because the `mean(number)` of the group 2 is smaller than the `mean(number)` of the group 1, I would like to rename the `label == 1` to 2 and the `label == 2` to 1.

This example is just a small toy of my problem, imagine that I can have a huge number of label.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly longer than I'm sure what would otherwise be possible, but this should get you there:

We first summarise the data down to just get the unique values from `mean(number)` and then use the `rank()` function to find out which ones are larger.

Then we put this information back together with the original data using `full_join()` and merge with the `label` column.

```r
temp_update <- temp %>% 
  group_by(label) %>%
  summarise(mean_numb = mean(number)) %>% 
  mutate(rank = rank(mean_numb)) %>% 
  
  full_join(temp, by="label") %>% 
  arrange(rank)
```

You could make sure the names of the column are now replacing the original `label` column in the end using:

```r
temp_update %>% 
  mutate(label = rank, 
         rank = NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

For each `label` calculate the `mean` `number` and `arrange` the data according to their mean. You can then create a new label column (`new_label`) that would just be row numbers according to mean value. Join this data with the original data to get all the rows back.

```
library(dplyr)

temp %>%
  group_by(label) %>%
  summarise(mean_num = mean(number)) %>%
  arrange(mean_num) %>%
  mutate(new_label = row_number()) %>%
  inner_join(temp, by = 'label')

#   label mean_num new_label number
#   <fct>    <dbl>     <int>  <dbl>
# 1 2         5.47         1   3.23
# 2 2         5.47         1   5.64
# 3 2         5.47         1   7.46
# 4 2         5.47         1   5.76
# 5 2         5.47         1   5.28
# 6 1         9.63         2   7.01
# 7 1         9.63         2  10.5 
# 8 1         9.63         2   7.86
# 9 1         9.63         2  11.2 
#10 1         9.63         2  11.6
```

I have kept both `label` and `new_label` column in the final output for comparison purposes. You can remove `label` column using `%>% select(-label)` if it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is the same approach using `data.table` and the `frank` function (you might want to adjust the ranking method for ties, depending on how you want to rank and label two groups with the same mean):

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(temp)
setkey(temp[temp[, .(mean_numb=mean(number)), by=label][, new_label:=frank(mean_numb)], 
            on="label"], new_label)[]
#>     label    number mean_numb new_label
#>  1:     2  3.227782  5.474131         1
#>  2:     2  5.640527  5.474131         1
#>  3:     2  7.462095  5.474131         1
#>  4:     2  5.757175  5.474131         1
#>  5:     2  5.283074  5.474131         1
#>  6:     1  7.013043  9.631682         2
#>  7:     1 10.518136  9.631682         2
#>  8:     1  7.862838  9.631682         2
#>  9:     1 11.181122  9.631682         2
#> 10:     1 11.583271  9.631682         2
```